# There are $n$ islands with $n$ bridges connecting pairs of islands (where $n\ge 2$). Prove that some sequence of distinct bridges forms a loop.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ islands with $n$ bridges connecting pairs of islands (where $n\ge 2$). Prove that some sequence of distinct bridges forms a loop.

I started with some values but I could not find a similarity between them.  Solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suppose you add bridges one at a time.  After you have added $k$ bridges, if you have not formed any loops, at least how many islands must be involved?